# JavaScript alert is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, button, alert, silverstripe

I have tried many ways to make JavaScript alert pop up but it is not working.

My website is in SilverStripe 3.1. I am using jQuery.

There is no error in the JavaScript file or the web console. The JavaScript file has loaded on the page. All mt other functions (.remove, .ajaxbtn, .gotocart, and checkout) work correctly. Only the alert call does not work.

Here is my JavaScript file:

```
(function($)
{
    $(document).ready(function() 
    {
        $('.ajaxbtn').on( 'click', function() 
        {
            event.preventDefault();
            var link = $(this).attr('href'); 
            var request = $.ajax(
            {
              url: link,
              type: 'GET',
              dataType: 'html'
            });
            $('.ajaxbtn').ajaxSuccess(function()
            {
                alert('AJAX request successfully completed');
            });
            alert('AJAX request successfully completed');
        });

        $('body').on( 'click', '.remove',function() 
        {
            //event.preventDefault();
            var link = $(this).attr('href'); 
            //console.log(dataid);

            var request = $.ajax(
            {
              url: link,
              type: 'GET',
              dataType: 'html'
            });
        });

        $('body').on( 'click', '.checkout', function() 
        {
            //event.preventDefault();
            var link = $(this).attr('href'); 
            //console.log(dataid);

            var request = $.ajax(
            {
              url: link,
              type: 'GET',
              dataType: 'html'
            });
        });

        $( '.gotocart' ).click(function() 
        {

            alert('asdasdas');
            var link = $(this).attr('href'); 
            var request = $.ajax(
            {
              url: 'member-area/product-page-2/product-gallery/OrderedTemplate/',
              type: 'GET',
              dataType: 'html'
            });
            request.done(function( msg ) 
            {
                $('.cartcontent' ).replaceWith(msg);
            });
        });
    });
}(jQuery));
```

Here is the html for my buttons:

```
<button class="ajaxbtn btn btn-primary" href="$Top.Link(Cart)?id=$ID">Pick</button>
<button class="remove btn btn-primary" href="$Top.Link(RemoveItem)?id=$ID">Remove</button>
<button class="checkout pull-right btn btn-primary" style="margin-right:10px;" href="$Top.Link(CheckOut)?id=$ID">Check Out</button>
<button class="gotocart pull-right btn btn-primary" style="margin-right:20px" href="$Top.Link(gotoCart)">Go to cart</button>
```

Comment: You have multiple alerts, are they all not firing? Seems to work in this JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/LrhuynL5/

Comment: I found out the problem, I accidentally closed the Pop-ups function in google chrome. Thanks btw~

Answer (score 2):

I believe .ajaxSuccess() should be attached to the document, and not a particular element. So `$(document).ajaxSuccess();`.

- Also, you should probably move that outside the button's click handler, otherwise you are binding the success event again and again every time the button is clicked.

Comment: good! +1 As of jQuery 1.8, the `.ajaxSuccess()` method should only be attached to document.

Comment: made a fiddle... look at the bottom on javascript area.. http://jsfiddle.net/65Lw3prx/

Comment: tried this:
$(document).ajaxSuccess(function()
{
   alert('AJAX request successfully completed');
});
  
$('.ajaxbtn').on( 'click', function() 
{
 event.preventDefault();
 var link = $(this).attr('href'); 
 var request = $.ajax(
 {
  url: link,
  type: 'GET',
  dataType: 'html',
  success: function(data) 
  {
   alert('AJAX request successfully completed');
  }
 });
});
but same result, nth happen.

Comment: I found out the problem, I accidentally closed the Pop-ups function in google chrome. Thanks btw~

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried writing `success` inside the `$.ajax` function? Something like this:

```
var request = $.ajax({
            url: link,
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'html',
            success: function(data) {
            alert('AJAX request successfully completed');
          }
        });
```

You can also try using `request.done` which you have used in the second ajax call.

Comment: I forgot to add, remove the `.ajaxSuccess()` call from the element

Answer (score 0):

add a `success`callback inside your `$.ajax` call.

```
var request = $.ajax(
          {
              url: link,
              type: 'GET',
              dataType: 'html'
            });
```